# Using brackets in dynamic .NET expressions

Tags: .net, dynamic, linq-expressions

I have a grid in witch a user can fill-in the "filter" on a collection.
The user has to fill-in some columns:

```
AndOr  Property  Comparator  Value
```

say, for a Cities collection it could filter cities that

```
   -  Name       StartsWith  'a'
  AND Population     >       10000
  OR  Population     <       1000
```

I used the dynamic [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), that worked very well, until the "brackets"  requirement appeared.

As you can see from the "query" above, in the resulting collection we will have cities which
`(Name.StartsWith'a' AND Population > 10000) OR (Population < 1000)`.

In order to build the expression
 `Name.StartsWith'a' AND (Population > 10000 OR (Population < 1000)`
I need to use some brackets.

Now, the filter grid columns changed to

```
AndOr  LeftBracket  Property  Comparator  Value  RightBracket
```

Is there some "Group", "Open/CloseBracket" in the .NET Dynamic Expression library?
An other way to realize it?

The code to "link" rows between them was the following

```
Private Function GetMyObjectsDataSource() As IQueryable(Of MyObject)
  ' start without any filter, get it all '
  Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)()
  Dim filterExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of MyObject, Boolean)) = predicate

  For Each row In grdFilter.Rows
    Dim rowExpression = GetExpressionFromRow(Of MyObject)(row)
    Dim compOp As LogicalOperator = row.Cells(ColumnKeys.AndOr).Value

    If compOp = LogicalOperator.Or Then
      filterExpression = [Or](filterExpression, rowExpression)
    Else
      filterExpression = [And](filterExpression, rowExpression)
    End If
  Next row

  Dim myObjects As List(Of MyObject) = Me._Container.GetMyObjects()
  Dim result As IQueryable(Of MyObject) =
    myObjects.AsQueryable().Where(filterExpression)

  Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I think it is the `Block` expression, but not sure.

Comment: @leppie: unfortnately don't see how to use the block expression in my case...

Comment: @leppie: A Block expression is used to group several expressions together such that they execute in sequence (analagous to a block of code). (now have enough rep to comment on the question)

Comment: I may be missing something, but in what way is the material in the 'Nesting Predicates' section of [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) insufficient? Are you looking for guidance on how to *represent* a predicate containing grouping?

Comment: @AAkashM: I think the poster is looking for a more generalized explanation of how to dynamically compose the nested predicate and where the best place to insert it into the existing code would be.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with this is to use nested sub-expressions in your expression tree.  This likely involves changing the way you are interpreting the user's input.  Basically whenever you encounter a LeftBracket element, you would recursively build a sub-expression up to the next RightBracket element in the current scope.  Then you would assign that entire sub-expression as a node in the current operation.

From reviewing the code sample in your question, I would suspect the best place to do this is in the "GetExpressionFromRow" function.  Unfortunately, I don't think the "GetExpressionFromRow" is part of the code library you referenced in your question.

If you can update your question to include the GetExpressionFromRow and dependencies, I can try to examine further and give a more specific answer.

The basic algorithm behind this technique is called a recursive descent parser.  See some general information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: As a side-note @leppie (can't comment on the question due to insufficient reputation), a Block expression is not the correct answer here.  A Block expression is used to group several expressions together such that they execute in sequence (analagous to a block of code)