# Sample expression Evaluator

Tags: .net, algorithm

Say I need to evaluate a expression as true or false starting from a sample input string like
`True or False or ( False or True )`
we suppose do not do any validation check.

Bellow we have a working sample that don't use brackets, and I need to add the brackets support...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            // suppose the user introduces a valid input like:
            // True or False or ( False or True )
            var stringTokens = input.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

            List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>();

            foreach (string token in stringTokens)
            {
                tokens.Add(new Token(token));
            }

            bool result = Token.GetResult(tokens.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("The result is - {0}!", result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        class Token
        {
            public readonly Linker Linker;
            public readonly bool? Value;

            public Token(string text)
            {
                switch (text.Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    case "true":
                        Value = true; break;
                    case "false":
                        Value = false; break;
                    case "(":
                        Linker = Program.Linker.LeftBracket; break;
                    case ")":
                        Linker = Program.Linker.RightBracket; break;
                    case "and":
                        Linker = Program.Linker.And; break;
                    case "or":
                        Linker = Program.Linker.Or; break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }

            public bool IsLinker
            { get { return !Value.HasValue; } }

            public static bool GetResult(params Token[] tokens)
            {
                bool result = true;

                Linker previousLinker = Linker.And;

                // this is some bull code...
                // please help
                foreach (var token in tokens)
                {
                    if (token.IsLinker)
                        previousLinker = token.Linker;
                    else
                    {
                        if (previousLinker == Linker.And)
                            result = result && token.Value.Value;
                        else if (previousLinker == Linker.And)
                            result = result || token.Value.Value;
                        else // brackets
                        {
                            previousLinker = Linker.And;
                            //result = result; // NO idea here...
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public enum Linker
        {
            None, And, Or,
            LeftBracket,
            RightBracket
        }
    }
}
```

I should mention that I can't use the *Dynamic Link Library*, because I already use it... in fact, my question is strongly linked with this one: [Using brackets in dynamic .NET expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7306101/185593)

I just want to understand how to group some booleans with brackets... Thanks!

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that your problem is solvable using RPN. It's a standard way that i.e. calculators evaluate expressions such as: 5 * (9 + 4) - your expression is even simpler and contains only [and] and [or] operators.

Comment: @empi: is not about RPN. I have the initial condition BRACKETS, so I cant and will not do anything but brackets, because I am imposed to do it.

Comment: RPN is a way to solve expressions that contain brackets. You don't define problem in RPN - you translate to RPN and then you solve it.

Comment: @empi: OK.... I think I understand... ) will have a look...

Comment: I updated my answer - some time ago I wrote something very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `GetResult` function recursive.

When your foreach loop meets `Linker.LeftBracket` it should call `GetResult(nonProcessedTokents)` without the processed tokens. And when your loop meets `Linker.RightBracket` it'd evaluate and return the result. This method'll help to handle with nested brackets too. Something like that:

```
GetResult(Tokens.Skip(parsedTokensCount).Take(Tokens.Length-parsedTokensCount)
```

Or try this library: [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it using the C# compiler. (You have to secure the input string form injection)

```
public bool Evaluate(string value)
{
    const string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace Test
    {{
        public class TestClass
        {{
            public bool Eval()
            {{
                return {0};
            }}
        }}
    }}";
    value = value.ToLower().Replace("or", "||").Replace("and", "&&");
    using(var icc =  CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
    {
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters()
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        var cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, string.Format(code, value));
        var assembly = cr.CompiledAssembly;
        var sourceClass = assembly.CreateInstance("Test.TestClass");
        return (bool)sourceClass.GetType().InvokeMember("Eval", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sourceClass, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to solve your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306101/using-brackets-in-dynamic-net-expressions) using this technique also.

Comment: There is a little more complicated, because the output is not a bool, but a `Expression(Of Func(Of MyObject, Boolean))`, but if you have a solution there are some bounty on that question )

Comment: Your code works excellent on that concrete task. Thanks! However, conceptually I have independent elements(tokens) that can be ANDed or ORred, and now I see that the question was more about it... In the light of my other question you mentioned, there are some Expressions that is applicable to filter a collection. Now, I probably don't see all the possibilities of the "runtime compilation" but I am hard to figure out how to apply this solution on the non standard language elements like "Expressions" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but aren't you looking for something like [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)? It allows to handle such expressions without using brackets.

This algorithm explains how to translate your notation to RPN - [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Your problem is much simpler because you have less operators.

Some time ago I wrote something very similar: http://www.copypastecode.com/77935/ - it has some more features (i.e. it keeps order of operations). It is based on IPredicateExpression that is defined as something that takes an object and returns bool.

Comment: I am afraid not... user will be able to use explicitly brackets like in a "natural" expression.

Comment: Ok, I've read your first question and I'm even more confused. Do you have expression you want to evaluate or do you want to build an expression? On PredicateBuilder page there is information about inner predicate that basically represents the brackets - I guess it is not suitable for you - why?

Comment: in fact, I have a grid that represents a filter on some collection. in that grid a row represents a filter-condition, that is evaluated to "true" or "false" (say, Population for a City > 100 can be true or false). I just need to be able to group that rows if the user will use brackets in a arbitrary order between them.

Comment: do you need to construct expression that is then translated to i.e. sql or do you just want to evaluate it?

Comment: No, I just have some conditions that should met a object from a filtered collection. I apply that conditions for each of the object in the collection and I obtain a new collection that contains only objects that respects that conditions. Any SQL. I can already filter the objects without using brackets. I want to learn how to use brackets.

Comment: @serhio - RPN and Shunting-yard algorithm is a way to solve it. That is a standard way to solve such problems. You have an expression like (2+3)*5, it is translated to (with algorithm in my answer) to 2 3 + 5 *, evaluated => profit! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you decide rolling your own isn't the easiest approach, [SoftCircuits.ExpressionEvaluator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.ExpressionEvaluator/) on NuGet will evaluate expressions and even supports strings and custom functions or symbols. Disclaimer: I'm the one who wrote it.